# Laravel ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model []

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I get this error when running my test:

> ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Content]

Here is my test:

```
/** @test */
public function it_loads_homepage()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $response = $this->get('/');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public function home()
{
    $topbar = Content::where('slug', 'topbar')->firstOrFail();

    return view('welcome')->with([
        'logo' => Arr::get($topbar->content, 'logo', asset('images/logo.png')),
        'quote' => Arr::get($topbar->content, 'quote'),
        'quote_author' => Arr::get($topbar->content, 'quote_author')
    ]);
}
```

Here is my routes file:

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@home');

Route::post('/admin/content', 'ContentsController@store');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::middleware('auth')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardsController@index');
    Route::patch('/contents/{content}', 'ContentsController@update');
});
```

If anyone has any idea on how to help that would be much appreciated, thank you!

P.S. If I need to include anything else please let me know Thank you!

Comment: `Content::where('slug', 'topbar')->firstOrFail();` The or fail part is throwing the exception. Make sure the record exists when testing.

Comment: Yes the test just makes sure that the page load returns 200 status code. I have verified that the record does exist.

Answer (score 1):

The find() method from query builder can return a Model instance or null if no record was found in database. So you have to handle this by checking first if user exists. If he does you can for example show his avatar, otherwise you can show login button.

Your code is a bit messy and I would advice you to not mix logic with view code. You should get user in controller then pass him to view like

```
$topbar = Content::where('slug', 'topbar')->get()->toArray();

return view('welcome')->with([
    'logo' => Arr::get($topbar->content, 'logo', asset('images/logo.png')),
    'quote' => Arr::get($topbar->content, 'quote'),
    'quote_author' => Arr::get($topbar->content, 'quote_author')
]);
```

Comment: The content dB table has a content column which stores JSON. This logic is in my controller not in my view.

Comment: The JSON contains all the data for the record

Answer (score 1):

The exception tells you that there isn't a `Content` object that matches the condition. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models):

> #### Not Found Exceptions
>
> Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found.
>   This is particularly useful in routes or controllers. The `findOrFail`
>   and `firstOrFail` methods will retrieve the first result of the query;
>   however, if no result is found, a 
>   `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown.

Check out your `where` condition:

```
$topbar = Content::where('slug', 'topbar')->firstOrFail();
```

Make sure you have a record in your `contents` (?) table with the `slug=topbar` (remember this is case-sensitive). You said in one of your comments that you are sure, so check it in the [Artisan Console](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan) using [Tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#tinker):

```
$ php artisan tinker
> Content::where('slug','topbar')->count();
```

This should output:

> [!] Aliasing 'Usage' to 'App\Content' for this Tinker session.
>
> => 1        // or maybe more..

To get your records you can try this instead (in your controller):

```
$topbar = Content::where('slug', 'LIKE', '%topbar%')->firstOrFail();
```

Also, its very likely that your sentence is just a sample of your current code, but if not, make sure to pass the actual value in your where clause:

```
$topbar = Content::where('slug', 'LIKE', request('slug'))->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at that tomorrow